# Aggregate function shows more than one results

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I take the customer_name the query column only generates a value, however again when I insert the column to query displays various results. Can anyone help?

```
select 
    max(valor_total) as "Valor", 
    date_part('Month', data_compra) as mes, 
    date_part('Year', data_compra),
    nome_cliente
from 
    compra, cliente
where 
    data_compra::text like '2015-%'
    and cliente.cpf_cliente = compra.cpf_cliente
group by 
    2, 3, 4
order by 
    2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we can't guess what your problem is without seeing any code. Please, edit your post with your query, also your table structure. Sample data from your table (or tables) and what would be your desired result.

Comment: Probably your clients have different names. If they all had the same name then you would get a single value per year\month.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Anything that it not a aggregate (i.e. anything you need to add to the group by section) will create seperate row instances if they are different.

In your instance, any differing values of the

```
Month ~ date_part('Month', data_compra) as mes, 
Year ~ date_part('Year', data_compra),
Client Name ~ nome_cliente
```

will give another row.
e.g. 1 row for the month of Dec(12), one row for the month of Nov(11)